# Definition of profession: coasterman

Tags: palaeography, terminology, profession

In the 1930 census appears the profession *coasterman* (see image below). The person worked in a restaurant but I have not been able to find a definition. (other workers in restaurants could be waiters, short order, etc.)

Would anyone know the meaning of this job?

[image]

Here is a larger sample of the census record :

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it might be rather *Counterman*? The letter combination in the occupation doesn't quite appear to match the "st" in "restaurant"  Do you have other examples of letters (ideally with the pairing "nt") written in the same hand for comparison?

Comment: You are more very certainly right, it should read counterman. Could you make this into an answer? - Thank you.

Comment: If someone has time to look on Google Books or the usual places, it would be useful if we could dig up a list of occupations that the enumerators would have used. I'll ask on History Hub and see if my census experts know. Linking to the enumerators' materials, where appropriate, would give answers to these handwriting questions more weight than simply posting "I think it looks like X" answers.

Comment: What regards this question, counterman is a well-defined profession (see e.g. OED).

Comment: Just FYI, the modern materials are at https://www.census.gov/topics/employment/industry-occupation/guidance/indexes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The letter combination that you read as 'st' in the occupation doesn't appear to match the 'st' combination in the adjacent word "*Resturant*" [sic].

I wondered, therefore whether the word might actually be "***Counterman***" (i.e. a waiter to served from behind a counter, rather than providing table service).

A quick check of the [1930 Census: Classified Index of Occupations](https://www.census.gov/library/publications/1930/dec/occupation-index-class.html) gave me the occupation:

> Counter man, café or restaurant

on page 200, which is probably what you are looking at in this instance.

[image: List of waiter occupations]